# How to tell if an egg is raw or hard boiled? Why doesn't light go through?

Tags: optics, everyday-life

A follow up question to this eggceedingly good  one [Why do rotten eggs float in water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/638847/why-do-rotten-eggs-float-in-water/638851#638851)

There are already some good methods here

https://www.wikihow.com/Tell-If-Eggs-Are-Raw-or-Hard-Boiled

It's clear enough why most of the methods work but...

In 'other tests' number 3, a torch is shone through the egg, but why does the boiled egg not allow as much light through as the liquid egg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods in the link you give are good.

> In 'other tests' number 3, a torch is shone through the egg, but why does the boiled egg not allow as much light through as the liquid egg?

Have you never cracked a raw egg? The uncooked white is not white, it is a colorless jelly. When you shine a light through, it is only the yolk that will stop diffusion. If it is boiled, hard or soft, the white has coagulated and light does not go through.

Comment: Thankyou, although is there also an explanation known for why the same substance, when cooked, becomes opaque, or does that get really complicated?

Comment: @JohnHunter Complicated. https://news.ncsu.edu/2019/01/why-do-egg-whites-turn-white-when-you-cook-them When egg whites are raw, their proteins are curled up into tight balls. When heat is applied, those proteins uncoil and get tangled, forming a kind of mesh, which traps the surrounding water. This changes the color and the physical consistency of the egg white.

Comment: @anna v thanks, good answer

Comment: And in fact,  this is why raw eggs are, or used to be, "candled."  In a dim room, an inspector would place each egg in front of a light source. If significant embryonic development was seen, the egg would not be included in saleable items.